# QML multi show Text and gif like weibo

Tags: html, text, qml

I meet a serious question
when i use text with html
like this:

```
 Rectangle {
width: 100
height: 62
Text {
    id: name
    text: "stackflow i am coming....<src img=http://www.google.com/yitb.gif />"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```

}

but result it like this:
  gif file can't show animation,but png file can show it normal
  so i need help to show it normal

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can used animated images like GIF files in an Text element.
If you want to see the animated version of the image your have to use the [QML AnimatedImage Element](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animatedimage.html) I guess.

Comment: thinks,but i should show some texts and some faces like skype,And i don't know how much  texts and faces in A few paragraphs.i read some about html, it can support gif files in html

Comment: Well you can use dynamic Views in QML if you don't know how many elements you are going to need. For example a ListView and you have one item for each chat message or something you know. You can also create completely dynamic views with JavaScript. I would not use HTML in Text elements unless you have to.

Comment: Think you! Can you show one example for me,I use listview and it'delegate is very complex which contains sub listview,but how to show dynamic pic and text ,i have no idea in qml,because i can't get how much face in a few paragrahs,Please.

Comment: yeah i could show you an example but I need more details what you wanna do exactly, also its impossible to write code here in the comment section that looks terrible and not enough space I guess :D

Comment: what is your email address,i can send E-mail to you which can contains some details of the must

Comment: I think it's better if you post your details on the official Qt forums maybe? http://qt-project.org/forums there might be other users who might also help you :)

Comment: think you!I post it to Qt-project